# How to disable Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I aware that this will be a less programming question, but still...

How can I completely disable fiddler. I went to options->connections and unchecked all checkboxes, disabled File->capture traffic, went to IE and disabled Fiddler addin, went to connections and removed all proxies and still all my pages (on IE and chrome, FF is fine) go through fiddler. All would be good if Fiddler wouldn't break that much, especially when sending lots of files.
When I tried to uninstall fiddler completely all pages just stopped working at all

So how do I disable Fiddler say in IE or better in whole system.

This drives me crazy for few weeks already :(

Comment: How do you know they are going through Fiddler?  Is this a server OS?

Comment: If I close it everything stops working plus I see requests in fiddler if it's being started

Comment: @Sergej: If you can close Fiddler, then Fiddler isn't running, so disabling it isn't the issue. I recently had an issue where certain programs, including FireFox, could not communicate with the Internet unless Fiddler was running. This turns out to have been due to the antivirus/security software on my PC. It would only permit programs it knew to access the Internet. It knew about Fiddler, not about FireFox.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I try not to post answers to my own questions. But I decided to do it this time. After two weeks of strugling I gave all my attention to this problem today.

It appears that a proxy was set in VPN. I didn't know that you can set proxy to a VPN connection. In Network settings go to your VPN connection, then to proxy and disable Fiddler there too

Comment: Well still I don't trust my eyes when fiddler is installed, but that time I resolved this issue by going to Internet Properties window -> Connectios
1. Disable "Lan Settings" -> "Use proxy server for your LAN..."
2. Select your VPN connection, "Properties" -> "Use proxy server for this connection..."

Comment: I found that if my computer crashed or is abruptly powered off, then this proxy setting has to be manually reverted, because Fiddler didn't get a chance to revert it during shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

I was not aware that Fiddler could run by itself, without you having started it. It seems to me that if you don't see Fiddler, then it's not there.

This could be why it's driven you crazy trying to disable it - it's not there.

Comment: Fiddler doesn't run by itself. In this case, his proxy settings were pointed at a non-existent instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can completely uninstall fiddler but you must go into the fiddler folder itself (\Program Files\Fiddler2 by default) where a uninst.exe will be found.  That will remove it completly.  Otherwise, you can disable it from the add-ons menu in firefox.

Comment: Fiddler is uninstalled using the Add/Remove Programs option in the system control panel, like every other properly-written Windows app.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you need to disable the plug-in in the internet explorer settings.

Internet Properties -> Programs -> Manage Add-ons

Comment: The Fiddler "add-on" is simply a button that launches it. It has no impact on anything to do with the system proxy.